# Consolidate duplicate rows of an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array that I need to consolidate by combining the rows with duplicate entries (based on the first column), while preserving any positive values of the other columns. My array looks like this.

```
array([[117,   0,   1,   0,   0,   0],
       [163,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [117,   0,   0,   0,   0,   1],
       [120,   0,   1,   0,   0,   0],
       [189,   0,   0,   0,   1,   0],
       [117,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [120,   0,   0,   1,   0,   0]])
```

I'm trying to make the output look like this:

```
array([[117,   1,   1,   0,   0,   1],
       [120,   0,   1,   1,   0,   0],
       [163,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [189,   0,   0,   0,   1,   0]])
```

I've been able to use `unique` on column zero to filter out the duplicates, but I can't seem to preserve the values of the other columns. I would appreciate any input!

Comment: This is certainly possible (but a little fiddly) in NumPy. Are you open to solutions in other libraries?

Comment: Yes, I'm open to other libraries.

Comment: And does the order of the returned rows matter (e.g. can the first column be `117, 120, 163, 189`)?

Comment: The order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pure NumPy solution could work like this (I've named your starting array `a`):

```
>>> b = a[np.argsort(a[:, 0])]
>>> grps, idx = np.unique(b[:, 0], return_index=True)
>>> counts = np.add.reduceat(b[:, 1:], idx)
>>> np.column_stack((grps, counts))
array([[117,   1,   1,   0,   0,   1],
       [120,   0,   1,   1,   0,   0],
       [163,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [189,   0,   0,   0,   1,   0]])
```

This returns the rows in sorted order (by label).

A solution in [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) is possible in fewer lines (and potentially uses less additional memory than the NumPy method):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(a)
>>> df.groupby(0, sort=False, as_index=False).sum().values
array([[117,   1,   1,   0,   0,   1],
       [163,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [120,   0,   1,   1,   0,   0],
       [189,   0,   0,   0,   1,   0]])
```

The `sort=False` parameter means that the rows are returned in the order the unique labels were first encountered.

Comment: Just beat me to the pandas solution. +1

Comment: Cheers - yep, I think pandas is often the way to go with these grouping/aggregation problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind that the rows are re-ordered randomly, then a dictionary hash could work.

```
def consolidate(input):
    unique = { }
    for row in input:
        id = row[0]
        if id not in unique:
            unique[id] = row
        else:
            for i in range(1, len(row)):
                unique[id][i] |= row[i]
    return unique.values()
```

This results in:-

```
[[120, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
 [163, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [117, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
 [189, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
```

If you *do* want row sequence to be preserved then a little more work is needed:-

```
def consolidate(input):
    unique = { }
    sequence = 0

    for row in input:
        id = row[0]
        row = [sequence] + row
        sequence += 1
        if id not in unique:
            unique[id] = row
        else:
            for i in range(2, len(row)):
                unique[id][i] |= row[i]
    return [row[1:] for row in sorted(unique.values())]
```

This now results in:-

```
[[117, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
 [163, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [120, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
 [189, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
```